# How to use AspectJ with Grails 3

Tags: gradle, grails, aop, aspectj

I would like to use AspectJ in my Grails 3.3.6 application. Spring AOP works very well but I need to use `call` pointcut designator which is not supported by Spring AOP.

This is my aspect file which is located under `src/main/java`

**TestAspect.aj**

```
public aspect TestAspect{
    pointcut executeMethod(): call(* com.example..*.*(..));  
    before(): executeMethod(){
        System.out.println("before " +thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName());
    }

    after(): executeMethod(){
        System.out.println("after "+thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

I tried [gradle aspectj plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/aspectj.gradle) and updated `build.gradle` as follows

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.aspectj:gradle-aspectj:0.1.6"
    }
}

project.ext {
    aspectjVersion = '1.9.1'
}

apply plugin:"java"
apply plugin: 'aspectj.gradle'
```

Application starts without any errors but my aspect is not working. Am I missing something ?

Using IntelliJ 2018.2.1 and Java 1.8.0_171

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats wrong with plain groovy metaprogramming magic? I can not imagine a situation, when a long outdated AOP can be better than that...

Comment: @injecteer You are definitely right. That was the first thing I tried but with grails I couldn't managed to do it maybe I was missing something but didn't have too much time to look at it. I have experience with aop so I gave it a try, however, I stucked at this problem :)

Comment: There is at least something "wrong" with plain groovy metaprogramming. Grails 3 changed spring/hibernate transactions to AST. So if you try to intercept a service method by replace invokeMethod, the transaction would still be flushed, committed only outside of that interception.